# Schedule job that will run as specific user

Tags: oracle, scheduler

I'm trying to create a job that will run a stored procedure as a specific user which I can create and provide with the limited permissions to do only what is required.

From what I have read I need to create the user (pretty standard) and then create a credential entry by performing;

```
dbms_scheduler.create_credential('[cred name]', '[Oracle User]', '[Oracle Password]');
```

Once I have the credential created I try to use it in the job creation script;

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'myJobName',
      job_type => 'stored_procedure',
      job_action => 'myStoredProcedure',
      credential_name => 'jobRunningUserCredential',
      destination_name => NULL);
```

The problem that I am having is that when this is run I get the following error message;

```
ora-27351 conflicting values of job attributes credential_name and job_type
```

I was wondering whether anyone can see something that I've missed out or whether I am just barking up the wrong tree with this approach in which case any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks for any help/advice in advance.

Sam

**UPDATE:**

After receiving the suggestion to use alter_chain I have implemented the following code;

```
dbms_scheduler.create_chain('myjob_chain', NULL, NULL, NULL);
dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step('myjob_chain', 'step_name', 'schemaName');
dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step('myjob_chain', 'parallel_instances', 'schemaName');
dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step('myjob_chain', 'enable_job', 'schemaName');
dbms_scheduler.enable('myjob_chain');

dbms_scheduler.alter_chain('myjob_chain', 'step_name', 'credential_name', 'myCredential');
dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'myJobName',
      job_type => 'stored_procedure',
      job_action => 'myStoredProcedure',
      credential_name => 'jobRunningUserCredential',
      destination_name => NULL);
dbms_output.put_line('job created');

dbms_scheduler.alter_chain('myjob_chain', 'set_parallel_instances', 'credential_name', 'myCredential');
dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(
    name => 'myJobName',
    attribute => 'parallel_instances',
    value => TRUE);
dbms_output_put_line('parallel_instances');

dbms_scheduler.alter_chain('myjob_chain', 'enable_job', 'credential_name', 'myCredential');
dbms_scheduler.enable(name => 'myJobName');
dbms_output_put_line('enable');
```

The output that this gives me is;

```
job created
parallel_instances
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-27351: conflicting values of job attributes CREDENTIAL_NAME and JOB_TYPE
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4395
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 2803
ORA-06512: at line 67
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to run a job as a specific user ,

- create credential for the particular OS not for the Database (Because the credential is pointing to the OS not to DB)

Create the credential

```
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_credential(
       username => 'OS Username',
        password => 'OS password',
        credential_name => 'TEST_CREDENTIAL'
    );
END;
```

Create the Job

```
   dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'myJobName',
      job_type => 'stored_procedure',
      job_action => 'myStoredProcedure',
      credential_name => 'TEST_CREDENTIAL',
      destination_name => NULL);
```

Now Run the Job ..

Answer (score 0):

> What you probably want to do is set the credential for the step.
>
> You can do this using `alter_chain` on the particular step with
>   attribute set to `credential_name` .
>
> http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CHDIAICJ

[Credit: Ravi](https://forums.oracle.com/message/9945654)

Comment: After adding a create_chain, create_chain_step and alter_chain I am still receiving the error message when I try to enable the job, I have updated the original question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want for the job to be run under userm, say, AJAX - you have to create the job under ths user. For that you have to grant him CREATE JOB privilege.

According to Oracle's [documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedover004.htm#BGBHJCHH) credentials are created as a comntainer for user/password information that is to be passed by Ora scheduler to **external** programs.

Therefore Your initial script had a misconception problem, trying to create a job with credentials (that is with parameter to call **external** program) and at the same time with job_type => 'stored_procedure' (and **stored_procedure** is a job type for calling internal pl/sql procedures).